# ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: customElements is not defined ReferenceError: customElements is not defined

Tags: angular

I have tried to implement 'add-to-calendar-button' on an angular 12 project, its working fine for angular without ssr eg for 'ng serve' but when I use the command for server-side rendering using 'npm run dev:ssr ' OR 'npm run build:ssr', It's also working and showing but when I reload particular module web page then its giving error and page is just loading.

Here is my code for reference:

EventsModule:

```
import { NgModule ,  CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { SingleEventDetailsComponent } from './single-event-details/single-event-details.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [SingleEventDetailsComponent , ....],
  imports: [... ],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
})
```

single-event-details.component.html

```
<span *ngIf="showCal">
                <add-to-calendar-button
                [attr.name]="eventTitle"
                options="'Apple', 'Google', 'iCal','Outlook.com', 'Yahoo'"
                [attr.location]="eventLocation"
                [attr.startDate]="calenderStartDate"
                [attr.endDate]="calenderEndDate"
                [attr.startTime]="eventStartTime"
                [attr.endTime]="eventendtTime"
                [attr.description]="eventDescription"
                [attr.label]="'buttons.ADD_TO_CALENDAR' | translate"
              ></add-to-calendar-button>
              </span>
```

single-event-details.component.ts

```
import 'add-to-calendar-button';
```

When we reload/refresh the web page related to the events module, it gives an error for SSR and the page gets continuously refreshing.

Error in command prompt :

ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: customElements is not defined
ReferenceError: customElements is not defined
enter image description here
[image]

https://www.npmjs.com/package/add-to-calendar-button/v/1.13.0 https://add-to-calendar-button.com/use-with-angular

https://add-to-calendar-button.com/use-with-angular

Answer (score 1):

Angular Universal (SSR) doesn't yet support web components and the add-to-calendar-button is a web component. https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/48746